# Closure of the inverse image under the projection map

Tags: gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids, ramsey-theory, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

Let $S$ be a subsemigroup of a semitopological semigroup $(T,+)$, let $e$ be an idempotent in $T\setminus S$ such that $e\in cl_T(S)$, let $\mathcal{E}$ be a subsemigroup of $S\times S$ such that $(e,e)\in cl_{T\times T}(\mathcal{E})$, and let $\pi_1:T\times T\rightarrow T$ be the projection homomorphism onto the first coordinate.

**Question:** For $A\subseteq \pi_1[\mathcal{E}]$, if $e\in cl_T(A)$, then can we say that $(e,e)\in cl_{T\times T}((A\times S)\cap\mathcal{E})$?

**Definitions:**

1. $e$ is an idempotent if $e+e=e$.
2. $cl_T(S)$ is the topological closure of $S$ in $T$.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

**P.S.** I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589995/closure-of-the-inverse-image-under-the-projection-map) on math.stackexchange.com, but didn't get any response.

Comment: In fact, this is a purely topological question as you can endow any topological space $X$ with the continuous semigroup operation $xy=x$. And in the topological setting a suitable example exists in the product of the sequential fan and the metric fan.